# Is the Chrome mobile emulator broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, responsive

It is either broken, or I don't really fully understand it. I have a Lumia 625 which has a 480x800 resolution. This is a screenshot from the Chrome Emulator with device set to 'Responsive' and res to 480x800:

[image]

I did attempt multiple refreshes, as I know it's sometimes bugged if not refreshed, however still the same result. Then I exited the emulator, and manually resized my browser window to 480x800 (Chrome shows the widthxheight when you resize) and it looks like this:

[image]

And finally, commited and published my website and tried it on my phone:
[image]

Now I have to say it's not pure HTML&CSS as I do use jQuery to style my page, but this really bugs me, as it seems to show very inconsistent results. How can I make sure the result I see is the one I'll see on the actual device? Also, if this is a known problem, I'd be very thankful to know if there's any other good emulator for mobiles/tablets out there? I really do love Chrome, but this emulator thing is just not doing it for me. :/

Comment: *How can I make sure the result I see is the one I'll see on the actual device?* Use the real device? Chrome can only emulate so far, and for the most part that isn't very far. If such a thing exists, a full emulator for the phone OS might be better.

Comment: Are there better emulators?

Comment: There is the iOS simulator for i-things, and various emulators for Android. I don't know about Windows phone emulators. I'm guessing the browser in question is more-like IE or Edge, than it is like Chrome. Perhaps test with those browsers?

Comment: This might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx